# How to display api running state when pressing back and coming again

Tags: flutter, dart

I am on a page, where I am calling an API. I am displaying progress while doing so. I want that when I press back and come to the page again, API should continue to run and the progress should remain intact. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Screen with WillPopScope:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
//hide progress here this will be called on presssing back button
        hideProgress()
        return false; // Allow back navigation
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Back Button Handling'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Press the back button'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```